# Django timezone same day diff is not 0

Tags: django, datetime, django-timezone

test function

```
from django.utils import timezone

def date_diff_now(date):
    print(date)
    print(timezone.now())
    print(date - timezone.now())
    print((date - timezone.now()).days)
```

Result

```
2018-02-07 17:46:36.442314+00:00
2018-02-07 17:47:32.084900+00:00
-1 day, 23:59:04.357374
-1
```

Why the difference between 2 datetime on the same day does not return 0 ?

Comment: What happens if you subtract the smaller from the larger? (ie: timezone.now() - date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Basic time and dates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

> If the normalized value of days lies outside the indicated range,
>   OverflowError is raised.
>
> Note that normalization of negative values may be surprising at first.
>   For example,

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> d = timedelta(microseconds=-1)
>>> (d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
(-1, 86399, 999999)
```

So it looks like a known overflow error.